# I think i forgot to flush my toilet before leaving for a 3 month vacation

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet

I kinda had an early morning flight and left in a hurry. I am not sure if i really flushed my toilet before leaving but i remember peeing. I don’t know how bad it’d be when i go back home. What’s the worst that could’ve happened? I’m really stressing :((

Comment: Three months is a long time, hopefully you had people checking on the house every few days.  The worst for the toilet is probably some extra cleaning, if nothing else happen in the house.  The toilet bowl water will be quite low and icky or even empty.

Comment: @crip659 Unfortunately, I didn’t :(. I am knew in the city and i didn’t know anyone i could trust enough to leave my house keys with

Comment: I would not be worrying about a dirty toilet.  If anything else happened, insurance will probably not pay.  There should be some home sitting companies around if you find yourself in the same way next time.

Comment: Of course if there's any leakage in the flush valve, the water may be slowly replacing itself whether you intend it to or not.

Comment: did you close the lid ?

Comment: @keshlam its a relatively new apartment so i don’t think there’s a leakage in flush valve?

Comment: @Ruskes It was almost 3 months ago so i really don’t remember atm. I’ll be going back in 2 weeks so i’ll get to see whether i did it or not ahahaha . It is my habit to always close the lid but i can’t recall if i did it while leaving in a haste

Comment: Well, it will all depend on the acidity of the pee

Comment: @crip659 well what else could’ve happened?

Comment: Three months with no one checking, a lot.  Being in an apartment building stuff would probably been found before doing too much, but leaking/burst pipes are the main thing leading to flooding, people breaking in and fires are others.

Comment: I did this as a lad before a 2 week vacation. The whole house stank like pee when we got back, but it only lingered a few hours.

Comment: @dandavis thats a little reassuring, except i have been away for almost 3 months :((((

Comment: @crip659 hmm breaking in is not a concern of mine. AND i’ll likely receive a notice or something from my building manager if there happens to be a pipe burst or something, i’d think?

Answer (score 4):

If it's just pee, the water will have evaporated and the toilet will be dirty. It might smell from the urine and from a possible dried out plumbing trap.  Just flush and clean when you get home.

Comment: it definitely was just pee!

Comment: @Jenli   So glad ... because I wasn't gonna go there if it wasn't.. no pun intended... lol